# Significance of Hank and Marie not having kid in Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad

Hank and Marie are happily married, except for small issues like when Marie was klepto. There is no hint in the show and I can't think of any reason why Hank and Marie have no kids. Is there a certain angle that needed this to make the show's plot better by making it more plausible or draw certain emotions in viewers, like the way things happened before Walt is left with his container full of money?

Comment: Not sourced or thought out enough to be an answer; but it helps draw a distinction between Walt being a typical average family man while Hank is a wild exciting care-free kind of guy.

Comment: @GendoIkari that is not a bad answer at all. Juxtapositions are often used to establish themes---I suspect based on what happens to each set, the show was trying to say something...

Comment: Maybe your assumption that happily married couple are bound to have kids is incorrect.

Comment: IIRC there's not much, if any, such discussion in the show. I just figured at the very least, Hank's job is one of the more dangerous you can have and if he wants to rise in the ranks, may be "better" (for lack of a better word)  to do that without having a child

Comment: Given how Marie is in love with the Whites' baby (Holly), and how she likes having their children at home, it seems she'd love to have one. Why they don't is not explicitly explained (Hank unwilling or a medical problem). But we can be sure of one thing, Hank's system is "working" (this is explicitly shown!).